# Python - Loop though dataframe and create class objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, bigdata

I have the following dataframe (already processed and cleaned to remove special chars, etc.).

| parent_id | members_id | item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| par_100 | member1 | item1 | t shirt |
| par_100 | member1 | item2 | denims |
| par_102 | member2 | item3 | shirt |
| par_103 | member3 | item4 | shorts |
| par_103 | member3 | item5 | blouse |
| par_103 | member4 | item6 | sweater |
| par_103 | member4 | item7 | hoodie |

and following class structure

```
class Member:
    
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.member_id = id
        self.items = []
        
class Item:
    
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.item_id = id
        self.name = name
```

The number of rows in the dataframe is around 500K+ . I want to create a dictionary (or other structure) where "parent_id" is the primary key and the columns are mapped to the class objects. After creating the specified data structure. I will be performing some actions based on some business logic where I will have to loop through all the members.

First action is to create the data structure from dataframe. I have following code which does the job but it takes around 3 hours to process all the 500k+ rows.

```
# sorted_data is the dataframe mentioned above
parent_key_list = sorted_data['parent_id'].unique().tolist()
    
    for index, parent_key in enumerate(parent_key_list):
    
        temp_data = sorted_data.loc[sorted_data['parent_id'] == parent_key]
        unique_members = temp_data["members_id"].unique()
    
        for us in unique_members:
            items = temp_data.loc[temp_data['members_id'] == us] 
           
            temp_member = Member(items[0]["members_id"])
    
            for index, row in items.iterrows():
                temp_member.items.append(Item(row["item_id"], row["item_name"]))
    
        parent_dict[parent_key].append(temp_member)
```

Since `.loc` is very time expensive operation, I tried the same thing with numpy arrays but the performance was much worse. Is there a better approach to reduce the processing time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

parent_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for (parent_id, members_id), sdf in sorted_data.groupby(['parent_id', 'members_id']):
    member = Member(members_id)
    items = sdf.apply(lambda r: Item(r.item_id, r.item_name), axis=1).to_list()
    member.items.extend(items)
    parent_dict[parent_id].append(member)
```

It makes use of the `.groupby` function to partition the dataset for each member. Then you can create the item objects using `.apply` on the subdataframes generated by `.groupby` and convert it to a list if `Item` objects that you can then use to update each member `items` attribute. Resulting members are stored in a `defaultdict` that you can convert back to a normal one using `dict()` (althought they works exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

You could use iterrows or itertuples to iterate the dataframe and initialize your instances. To make it a bit easier (if you insist on class, personally i would go with a dictionary for both members and items), I would do the following:

- Add a member id property to items
- Iterate the dataframe and initialize only item instances
- Afterwards, you can check all item instances so you can identify unique members and their items